# How can I rebuild my Photos.app library without losing any metadata?

Tags: photos, photos.app

I've had a photo library managed by my Mac since iPhoto on Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard. This library has migrated across every macOS update since then, migrated from iPhoto to Photos.app, and even moved across three Macs over those years.

However, I've been struggling for the last year or so that it never finishes recognizing people and even in my latest import of 1000 pictures a week ago, Photos.app on Ventura doesn't seem to be making much progress and even in the recent imports it isn't highlighting faces (unknown or otherwise). It feels like Photos.app is getting stuck.

I have noticed in the past by looking at the Console that Photos.app can blow up on files it doesn't know how to handle. For example, I had some old AVIs in the library that were recorded by an ancient Logitech device which had a codec that the Mac couldn't handle, and I eventually realized those files were landmines to photoanalysisd. I converted them with Handbrake and now they're modern and happy (the old AVIs were removed). I believe I only have "modern" files now. That being said, I still don't think things work right, but Console doesn't tell me enough to fix more files.

So what I'm looking for is if there is a way to take my entire photo library and get Photos.app to "start over". I've tried Photos repair applications, but that doesn't seem to fix it. What I think I'd like to try is to export EVERYTHING and start a new library and let the app start over from scratch. However, there is a ton of metadata in there (customized locations, comments, etc.) that I don't want to lose.

Is there a way to export and re-import without losing any metadata?

NOTE: While I do have iCloud shared libraries enabled, my main library is NOT stored on iCloud, it is ONLY on my local disks (yes, I do have backups!)

Comment: Do you use iCloud photo library?

Comment: @Ezekiel - No! I should have pointed that out. Will edit.

Comment: I ask only because that would allow you to re-build your library with metadata by creating a new blank library and assigning it as your system library, causing it to sync to the cloud. But sounds like not an option.